# Regex for HTML manipulation

Tags: php, html, regex, xpath, simplexml

What is the regex expression in order to have the following result, for **any** image inside **any** html td ?

from:

```
<td width="7" height="50" nowrap>
<img src="/images/img_1.png" width="7" height="50" alt="" />
</td>
```

to:

```
<td width="7" height="50" nowrap background="/images/img_1.png"></td>
```

Comment: Regex + HTML is a bad idea.  Look into using a DOM parser.

Comment: I retagged this for you to hopefully get a valid response. I'm not skilled enough with XPath, but hopefully someone will be able to give you a better response.

Comment: Thank you mkaatman, I appreciate your sugestion.

Comment: DomDocument is not voodoo :) Hope that helps!

Comment: That really helped Chris! :) Hope to retribute your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bad practice to use regular expressions to parse HTML. Instead, use the tools provided in PHP that are specifically geared toward parsing HTML, namely `DomDocument`[[doc](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)].

```
// create a new DomDocument object
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// load the HTML into the DomDocument object (this would be your source HTML)
$doc->loadHTML('
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="7" height="50" nowrap>
                <img src="/images/img_1.png" width="7" height="50" alt="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
');

//Loop through each <td> tag in the dom 
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('td') as $cell) {
    // grab any images in this cell
    $images = $cell->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if ($images->length >= 1) { // if an image is found
        $image = $images->item(0);
        // add the 'background' property to the cell, use the 'src' property
        $cell->setAttribute('background', $image->getAttribute('src'));
        // remove the image
        $cell->removeChild($image);
    }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

See it in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/x9ooyp

**Documentation**

- `DomDocument` - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
- `DomElement` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php
- `DomElement::getAttribute` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php
- `DOMElement::setAttribute` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php
- `DomDocument::loadHTMLFile` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php